# Draw images for documentation

Tags: data-structures, documentation, drawing

I am in need to draw some diagrams for documentation. Thinks like tables, flow charts, tree, etc.

I usually work in Linux environments and use Latex to write text and write mathematical formulas and equations. What else do you use to draw the things above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unsorted list of tools that I generally like:

- [PGF](http://ftp.univie.ac.at/packages/tex/help/Catalogue/entries/pgf.html): A really useful LaTeX macro package for drawing all kind of professional graphics.
- [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/): A tool to "program" directed graphs and other things with automatical layout.
- [Balsamique](http://www.balsamiq.com/): Web-tool for prototyping GUIs with PDF-export.
- Ascii-Art-Tools like [Ditaa](http://ditaa.sourceforge.net/) or [aafigure](https://launchpad.net/aafigure)
- [Dia Diagram Editor](http://dia-installer.de/): old but usefull GUI for drawing diagrams

Comment: Exactly what I needed! In fact better then I would expect! Thank you very much!!!